# Struggling with displaying Arabic tweets in python

Tags: python, tweepy

I am using Tweepy in Python (2.7) and I have been able to pullout a stream of tweets mixed as Arabic (ar) and English (en). The tweets that are written in Egnlish are preceded with "en" and they are properly readable. However, the ones written in Arabic, preceded by "ar", are not.

I would like to display the Arabic tweets in a readable fashion.

Your help is appreciated :)

```
alltweets = []  
new_tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name = 'SudanPMHamdok', count=200)
alltweets.extend(new_tweets)
oldest = alltweets[-1].id - 1
while len(new_tweets) > 0:
    new_tweets = api.user_timeline(screen_name = screen_name,count=200,max_id=oldest)
    alltweets.extend(new_tweets)
    oldest = alltweets[-1].id - 1
    print "...%s tweets downloaded so far" % (len(alltweets))
outtweets = [[tweet.id_str, tweet.created_at, tweet.text.encode("utf-8")] for tweet in alltweets]   

for t in outtweets:
     ...:     print t[0].encode("utf-8") ,",", t[3].encode("utf-8")
     ...:     print "_______________________"
```

[image]

Comment: if you want more details and the usage of what `I've mentioned, share your code,  but usually `.encode('utf-8', errors = 'ignore')` works fine

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have pasted the body of my script below.

Answer (score 0):

To convert these characters into something more useful, you will have to use [`encode` and `decode`](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html) to handle Unicode strings properly.

Answer (score 0):

To make yourself compatible with python3 and put this in the top of your file

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
```